# Bypassing HTML siblings with nested children

Tags: jquery

I want to loop through tablerows that are nested a few levels down the `<table>` tag.

What I thought I could do is something in the likes of

```
var row = jQuery("#views-form-transport-files-page > table > tbody > tr");
jQuery.each(row, function(index, value){
    console.log(value);
});
```

In my browser console, this outputs nothing at all. However, I tried outputting several elements, like elements closer to the parent. Most of the time, though if I wanted to output most elements through `console.log(".my-element-with-children");` I would get empty square brackets as a result, having an object on my hands.

So I'm really puzzled on how to target those `tr`s and loop through them If I can't use this `element > element > element` method?

```
    <div class="view view-transport-files view-id-transport_files view-display-id-page transport-files-view view-dom-id-03505a184244d1fde35eac370a04bbf4">

      <div class="view-filters">
      <form action="/transport-files" method="get" id="views-exposed-form-transport-files-page" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><div class="views-exposed-form">
  <div class="views-exposed-widgets clearfix">
          <div id="edit-field-transp-file-number-value-wrapper" class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-filter-field_transp_file_number_value">
                  <label for="edit-field-transp-file-number-value">
            Transport file number filter          </label>
                        <div class="views-widget">
          <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-transp-file-number-value">
 <input type="text" id="edit-field-transp-file-number-value" name="field_transp_file_number_value" value="" size="30" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
</div>
        </div>
      </div>
                    <div class="views-exposed-widget views-submit-button">
      <input type="submit" id="edit-submit-transport-files" name="" value="Apply" class="form-submit" />    </div>
      </div>
</div>
</div></form>    </div>


      <div class="view-content">
      <div class="views-form"><form action="/transport-files" method="post" id="views-form-transport-files-page" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-5qC8G26t49Mw4209HaFKb6GSX4Cnzt3sIsrcUvOobB8" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="rN22iXS4r0LeXV3rEEaAcVbWi8hOtvG_GyVP6PYICLQ" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="views_form_transport_files_page" />
<table class="views-table cols-29" >
        <thead>
      <tr>
                  <th class="views-field views-field-field-transp-file-number" >
            <a href="/transport-files?field_transp_file_number_value=&amp;order=field_transp_file_number&amp;sort=asc" title="sort by Transport file number" class="active">Transport file number</a>          </th>
                  <th class="views-field views-field-field-tf-customer" >
            Client          </th>
                  <th class="views-field views-field-field-tf-trailer-nr" >
            Trailer number          </th>

              </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          <tr class="odd transport-files-row views-row-first">
                  <td class="views-field views-field-field-transp-file-number" >
            <a href="/node/192/edit">43100021</a>          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-field-tf-customer" >
                      </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-field-tf-trailer-nr" >
            Trailer 3          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-field-transp-file-load-date" >
            <span class="date-display-single">2012-10-24</span>          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-field-tf-loading-place" >
                      </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-field-tf-driver-loading" >
                      </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-field-tf-deliv-ferry-comp" >
                      </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-field-deliv-ferry-price" >
                      </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-field-transp-file-deliv-date" >
            2012-10-24 00:00:00          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-field-tf-delivery-place" >
                      </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-field-tf-driver-deliverty" >
                      </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-field-tf-invoice-nr" >
            3366554488          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-field-tf-price-amount  views-field-editablefield" >
            <div id="editablefields-field-tf-price-amount" class="editablefield-item"><div class="field-type-number-float field-name-field-tf-price-amount field-widget-number form-wrapper" id="edit-field-tf-price-amount-0-field-tf-price-amount"><div                               id="field-tf-price-amount-0-field-tf-price-amount-add-more-wrapper"><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-tf-price-amount-0-field-tf-price-amount-und-0-value">
  <input type="text" id="edit-field-tf-price-amount-0-field-tf-price-amount-und-0-value" name="field_tf_price_amount[0][field_tf_price_amount][und][0][value]" value="5000" size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" />
</div>
</div></div><div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-field-tf-price-amount-0-actions"><input type="submit" id="edit-field-tf-price-amount-0-actions-submit" name="submit-field_tf_price_amount-0" value="Save" class="form-submit" /></div></div>          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-field-transp-file-currency  views-field-editablefield" >
            <div id="editablefields-field-transp-file-currency" class="editablefield-item"><div class="field-type-list-text field-name-field-transp-file-currency field-widget-options-select form-wrapper" id="edit-field-transp-file-currency-0-field-transp-file-currency"><div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-field-transp-file-currency-0-field-transp-file-currency-und">
  <label for="edit-field-transp-file-currency-0-field-transp-file-currency-und"> <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
 <select id="edit-field-transp-file-currency-0-field-transp-file-currency-und" name="field_transp_file_currency[0][field_transp_file_currency][und]" class="form-select required"><option value="€ "> €</option><option value="£ " selected="selected"> £</option></select>
</div>
</div><div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-field-transp-file-currency-0-actions"><input type="submit" id="edit-field-transp-file-currency-0-actions-submit" name="submit-field_transp_file_currency-0" value="Save" class="form-submit" /></div></div>          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-clone-node" >
            <a href="/node/192/clone?destination=transport-files">clone</a>          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-field-tf-baf-eb  views-field-editablefield" >
            <div id="editablefields-field-tf-baf-eb" class="editablefield-item"><div class="field-type-number-float field-name-field-tf-baf-eb field-widget-number form-wrapper" id="edit-field-tf-baf-eb-0-field-tf-baf-eb"><div id="field-tf-baf-eb-0-field-tf-baf-eb-add-more-wrapper"><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-tf-baf-eb-0-field-tf-baf-eb-und-0-value">
  <input type="text" id="edit-field-tf-baf-eb-0-field-tf-baf-eb-und-0-value" name="field_tf_baf_eb[0][field_tf_baf_eb][und][0][value]" value="" size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" />
</div>
           <td class="views-field views-field-field-tf-shunts-enz" >

                  <td class="views-field views-field-field-tf-with" >
                      </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-field-tf-ex" >
                      </td>
                  <td >
            <a href="/transport-file/mail/192">Mail sturen</a>          </td>
              </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

The idea is to target those nested input elements and apply `.onfocus();` and `.onfocus();` so I can calculate those values and put those values in another input element of the same row. So basically my client wants to use this `table` with a excel sheet like functionality.

Originally this table has many more td per row, but I pasted this shorter html because a lot of td are similar in structure.

Comment: Post the HTML you want to loop, so we can better help you.

Comment: The HTML is output by drupal and very large, I'll try and trim it

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) is for looping plain objects or arrays, but for looping jquery objects you better use the [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method, like this:

```
var row = jQuery("#views-form-transport-files-page > table > tbody > tr");
row.each(function(i) {
   console.log( $(this)[0].tagName );
});
```